# I need help extracting a word from a user entered string in Java

Tags: java, string

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hastags 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input a message directed towards a user with @, as well as a #hashtag and a URL: ");
        String status = input.nextLine();

        int hashtag = status.indexOf(" ");
        int hashtag2 = status.indexOf("#", hashtag );
        System.out.println(status.substring(hashtag2));

    }

}
```

I need the program to find the first instance of `#`, `@`, and a url beginning with `https://` inside a user entered string, and then print them back to the user. Right now it will find the hashtag, but will print the hashtag + the characters after it.

Example: `Input = Test #test Test, Output = #test Test`.

Comment: because substring() works that way. if u need just the index, why nor print the hashtag2 variable itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use

```
status.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```

In your case

```
status.substring(hashtag2, hashtag);
```

Otherwise it will use the whole input string after the index of the entered hashtag, which is more than just #test.

Edit: I just found another mistake in your code, you have to use

```
int startOfHashtag = status.indexOf("#");
int endOfHashtag = status.indexOf(" ", startOfHashtag);
String hashtag = status.substring(startOfHashtag, endOfHashtag);
```

Your way finds the first space and then search the hashtag from that position onwards, which is not what you want, I suppose.